# Expo push notifications does not appear after build

Tags: reactjs, react-native, push-notification, expo, apple-developer

I have react-native expo app. I use expo push notifications. I test them by [expo test notifications service](https://expo.dev/notifications). When I run `npx expo start` and I connect my iPhone (app runs in expo go) and I test its `ExponentPushToken` notifications show correctly.

The problem is when I build app by running `eas build`, I install it on iPhone, get new `ExponentPushToken` and test it. Notifications does not show and I don't get any errors.

What can be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

As I know you can't just use expo test notification service in production.

You got to have FCM or APN set up